# Why not make more use of the video generation logic?

Tags: apple-ii

The Apple II is famously built around its video generator. Conveniently, addresses are generated which scan all of the video memory and somehow spits the contents onto the screen.

Its occurred to me though, that generation of successive values which are put onto the address bus is useful for much more, because a single address can point to many different things at once. It could read a byte from a bitmap, and at the same time read some other value from another bank of memory. This is how the Apple II does DRAM refresh for example.

But couldn't this also have easily been used for many other purposes?

- **To scan the keyboard?** For example, we could map each address to a single key. Then, when a key is pressed, the address is stored in the keyboard latch and the 6502 is interrupted. This could probably mean the design could do without the AY-5-3600 which scans the keyboard.

Other ideas, probably too much feature creep for an Apple II, but maybe for another, more business-oriented computer.

- **Serial port I/O?** For as long as the serial port can supply us with bytes, just write them into some buffer to be read later by the CPU. Or write from the buffer to the port of course.
- **Multiple word arithmetic?** Now this is something which is quite tedious for a 6502. To add two 48 bit values for example is quite a long program. But if those values are in an appropriate bank of memory, then with the addresses being generated sequentially, a 78LS181 will blithely do the job. I suppose this could accelerate some heavy arithmetic, integer or floating point.

So I've never seen a computer design which uses the video addresses as something else at the same time. Why is this? Didn't occur to anyone? Or is there a technical reason?

Comment: The original Macintosh uses the video circuitry to fetch PCM audio data during the retrace. Specifically, exactly one byte per line, for ~22kHz 8-bit output. The MSX 2 onwards have an execution unit built into the VDP that can perform basic video manipulations during unused video memory cycles. Are those the sort of possibilities you were thinking of?

Comment: @Tommy that's exactly the sort of thing I mean. In the case of the macintosh, is the audio data stored at addresses derived from the addresses that make up the bitmap?

Answer (score 5):

What you are describing is called Direct Memory Access, or DMA. It is very common on computers nowadays but much less common when the Apple II came out.

The main issue is that it requires bus arbitration. The CPU and any DMA devices have to share the memory bus. In the Apple II the CPU, a 6502, only accesses the memory bus every other cycle so it wasn't difficult to have the video generation hardware to use every other cycle as well, avoiding the need for an arbitration.

If you try to add a third device to that bus there needs to be some way to manage and prioritize everything. The video hardware can't wait, it has to have priority or the display will glitch. The CPU can wait, but you need something that tells it to wait while the third device uses the bus.

Later machines such as the Amiga did exactly that, using custom chips to manage multiple DMA devices. The Apple II didn't have the luxury of using custom designed chips, it was all off-the-shelf hardware.

Comment: I wouldn't call scanning a keyboard matrix DMA...

Comment: Also I think, for example if we wanted to add a third device in the manner you suggest, no need for bus arbitration if that device can _share the address bus only_, using its own _data bus_. But I could be wrong about that

Comment: @Wilson how would the result of the scan be collected if not poked into memory somewhere? It could be done by a peripheral but then the utility of combining it with the screen refresh is absolutely minimal.

Comment: @Wilson interesting idea about using the address counters for something else, but it seems like it would be so inflexible and such a pain to use that it's not worth it. Plus the Apple II was designed to be low cost, and the lowest cost keyboard/serial ports are managed entirely in software.

Comment: @Wilson As said, it's just DMA. And in case of sharing, it doesn't mean if the components share all lines, or 'just' some. Address, Data and Control are one bus, and whenever any of these (or patrs thereof) are used, the whole bus must be reserved for that device. So all share the same bandwith, slowing down each other.

Comment: @Raffzahn I read Wilson's suggestion on sharing as: if a hypothetical video address generator is already outputting the sequence 1...n to fetch video then you could also feed those same address lines to something else, but have the data lines go elsewhere. That is, if there were somebody else who could also make use of the sequence 1...n, with the same timing. So I guess it's essentially sharing the address generator. Though Apple II video not being of the form 1...n or a permutation of the bits thereof, I don't have a good answer.

Comment: Which is again the same as DMA (ignoring for a monent, that different usages will need different values at the same time). Still, using the address generator to address something, it will block the address bus - thus disabling any other use. And if it's not connected to the address bus, it's not an address generator  - right? The whole thing doesn't make any sense.

Comment: No, I think he's envisaging a scenario in which a second device is added which uses *the same* addresses, in the same order, with the same running.

Comment: @Tommy you understand me correctly! Raffzahn I'm not a hardware guy, but I really don't understand why the address bus cannot supply the same value to several places at once?

Comment: @Wilson What would you do with the same address though? Seems like you would have your serial and keyboard data end up on the screen because they both read/write the same address. And you couldn't use the keyboard and serial at the same time.

Comment: @user unless there's other regions of memory that's (momentarily) mapped to the same addresses...? After all, that's kind of how DRAM refresh works on the Apple II.

Comment: @Wilson but if those memories are mapped on to the data bus then the video logic would read them too. Maybe you could have a separate data bus, but then you are adding a lot more hardware and would need separate or dual port RAM.

Comment: @user Your "maybe" is exactly what I am picturing. Hard to see how that means "a lot more hardware" though...

Comment: @Wilson well you need a separate data bus, separate RAM, and then some way for the CPU to access both data busses even though it is designed for just one. Maybe a load of buffering and switching. All for a relatively small gain.

Answer (score 1):

If one wants to use a timer-tick interrupt, keyboard scanning for an 8x8 keyboard can be handled very nicely using a pair of address strobes, a couple 74LS373 or equivalent chips. eight pull-up resistors, and eight diodes.  Commodore used a VIA or CIA chip in the VIC-20 and C64 so as to gain the timers and other resources therein, but if those weren't needed a simple pair of 8-wide latches with 3-state outputs would have been sufficient (or even one latch without 3-state outputs, and one 8-bit 3-state bus driver chip).

If one doesn't want to use interrupts, the value of piggy-backing keyboard scanning onto video would likely be rather limited.

Perhaps the biggest omission on the Apple II was the lack of any way of having video trigger an interrupt.  While it would be necessary to disable the interrupt during things like floppy-drive access, having a timer tick can be nice for a lot of things.  Having a soft switch gate the vertical sync output onto IRQ, using a counter rather than a 555 to control flashing, and feeding some outputs from that counter into general-purpose I/O pins would have made many things on the Apple II far more convenient than they ended up being.